# ForEach with ArraysList with different types objects

Tags: java

Classes Pravougaonik and Valjak both have the same methods racunajPovrsinu() and racunajObim(). I can finish this easy with two different ArrayList-es and 2 for Loops. This code works fine:

```
   List<Pravougaonik> pravougaonici = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3);
   List<Valjak> valjci = Arrays.asList(v1, v2, v3);

   for (Pravougaonik p : pravougaonici) {
        povUkupno += p.racunajPovrsinu();
        obimUkupno += p.racunajObim();

    } 
   for (Valjak v : valjci) {
        povUkupno += v.racunajPovrsinu();
        obimUkupno += v.racunajObim();

    }
```

But I need to create 1 ArrayList for all objects as I did here and calculate everything in 1 forEach loop, is it possible to do as i tried here:
This dont work:

```
List<Object> oblici = Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3,v1,v2,v3);
    
    
    for (Object o : oblici) {
        povUkupno += o.racunajPovrsinu();
        obimUkupno += o.racunajObim();

    }
```

Interface Izracunjliv:

```
public interface Izracunljiv {


public double racunajPovrsinu();
public double racunajObim();}
```

Class pravouganik methods:

```
@Override
public double racunajPovrsinu() {
    return this.a * this.b;
}

@Override
public double racunajObim() {
    return 2 * this.a + 2 * this.b;
}
```

Class valjak methods:

```
@Override
public double racunajPovrsinu() {
    return 2 * (Math.pow(this.r, 2) * Math.PI) + (2 * this.r * Math.PI * this.h);
}

@Override
public double racunajObim() {
    return 4 * this.r * Math.PI;
}
```

Comment: Don't. You don't want a list to hold unrelated types and this is a bad anti-pattern if you do. The types should relate *somehow*, be it by implementing the same interface or extending a same parent class.

Comment: I have implemented interface : public interface Izracunljiv {
    
    
    public double racunajPovrsinu();
    public double racunajObim();
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the pertinent code and additional explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `List` of type `Izracunljiv` instead of `Object`, since these methods are part of the `Izracunljiv` interface.